# android market not updating on phone

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am trying to test in-app billing in my Android application. The problem is, it appears my market is not up to date since I can't bind to the billing service(I am using the Android example code from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html). I keep getting the message **This app cannot connect to Market.
     Your version of Market may be out of date.
     You can continue to use this app but you
     won\'t be able to make purchases.**

I tried updating the market by opening it, hitting the home, and waiting 5-10 minutes and trying again as outlined [here](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?answer=190860), but it didn't fix the problem. I am testing on a Nexus One with no phone connection - just over WiFi(not sure if this is relevant) with OS 2.2. Has anyone else run into this problem?

Here is the code from my activity:

```
if (!mBillingService.checkBillingSupported()) {
    showDialog(DIALOG_CANNOT_CONNECT_ID);
}
```

and this is the code from my billing service that is showing the billing is not supported:

```
public boolean checkBillingSupported() {
    return new CheckBillingSupported().runRequest();
}

    class CheckBillingSupported extends BillingRequest {
    public CheckBillingSupported() {
        // This object is never created as a side effect of starting this
        // service so we pass -1 as the startId to indicate that we should
        // not stop this service after executing this request.
        super(-1);
    }

    @Override
    protected long run() throws RemoteException {
        Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("CHECK_BILLING_SUPPORTED");
        Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
        int responseCode = response.getInt(Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESPONSE_CODE);
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "CheckBillingSupported response code: " +
                    ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCode));
        }
        boolean billingSupported = (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK.ordinal());
        ResponseHandler.checkBillingSupportedResponse(billingSupported);
        return Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_INVALID_REQUEST_ID;
    }
}


    private boolean bindToMarketBillingService() {
    try {
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "binding to Market billing service");
        }
        boolean bindResult = bindService(
                new Intent(Consts.MARKET_BILLING_SERVICE_ACTION),
                this,  // ServiceConnection.
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        if (bindResult) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not bind to service.");
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Security exception: " + e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it requires the phone to have a mobile data connection. You can try to install the latest [market app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=19461601&postcount=8) manually.